# Is it ok to install python 3.2 in 11.10?

Tags: python

I'm just wondering if it is okay install the package python3.2 from ubuntu's repositories?. I have been so unlucky with ubuntu lately, that I'm afraid to do anything because everything seems to break my system.

The point is that I want to learn python 3, but without breaking the python dependencies of my system.

`sudo aptitude install -s python3.2` doesn't show any conflicts, but still I prefer to ask.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python 2.x and 3.x happily coexist on ubuntu.  All python scripts not specifically launched with python 3 will default to python 2 though.

```
aking1012@devlaptop:~$ python3
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  5 2011, 21:17:14) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
aking1012@devlaptop:~$ python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
```

If you're want to test 3 packages I would use something like Aptana where you can select which python dist you want to test under.

Credit to [James Henstridge](https://askubuntu.com/users/12469/james-henstridge) on suggesting the pseudo-package python3 over a specific version number.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that installing `python3` rather than `python3.2` is a better choice: on current releases it will have the same effect, but it has the benefit of easier upgrades when Python 3.3 gets integrated into a future Ubuntu release.

Comment: yes, that's how i installed it, but i forgot to mention that you should install pseudo-packages whenever you can